# script won't overwrite autostart

Tags: linux, scripting, debian, raspberry-pi, autostart

Here is the situation: I have a simple script which should add a line to the autostart file.
Instead of overwriting, it makes a new file with the same name. 
If i execute the script again it adds the line to the new autoscript file.

```
//script
echo 'some text' >> /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

When i look in the LXDE-pi map and do "ls" then there is autostart and "autostart?" 
so somehow it makes new file and adds an "?" instead of overwriting.

Short: how do i add a line in the autostart file with a script file?

EDIT:
this does the trick:
Found a solution:

I rename the file to something, then add a new line, and rename it back. And set the permissions back to executable.

mv autostart autostartBU
echo 'some text' >> autostart
mv autostartBU autostart
chmod 755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv autostart autostartBU
echo 'some text' >> autostart
mv autostartBU autostart
chmod 755
```